# Перемещение обьектов c#

Tags: c#

Как сделать перемещение обьектов формы с помощью мыши (picturebox к примеру), по человечески, а именно чтобы не искать обьект на который нажали и т.д. (что мне кажется решением через ж№%)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

События Drag'n'Drop. Информация [здесь](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.control.dragdrop.aspx)

и метод [DoDragDrop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.dragdrop.dodragdrop.aspx)

Comment: @Макс Жуков, копируйте, пожалуйста, если не сложно, ссылку на сам MSDN, а не на редирект через поиск Google. P.S. Про первую ссылку

Comment: @Spawn: отредактировал, думаю, автор не возражает

Comment: @Spawn, пардоньте, случайно.

Answer (score 0):

В крайнем случае можно просто отлавливать событие onMouseDown визуального компонента и в onMouseMove родительского виджета перемещать дочерний объект. При onMouseUp делать сброс.
Это костыльный способ, но он рабочий. Обычно в таких случаях принято использовать Drag`n`Drop, как это уже было замечено.